# ValueError: math domain error - Quadratic Equation (Python)

Tags: python, math, equation, quadratic

I'm very new to python programming and to this site. I'm currently working on a problem and can't seem to understand the error.

```
import math
# Problem number 5.
A5 = 5
B5 = 0
C5 = 6.5
# Root1
x9 = (-B5 + math.sqrt(B5**2 - 4*A5*C5))/(2*A5)
# Root2
x10 = (-B5 + math.sqrt(B5**2 - 4*A5*C5))/(2*A5)
# Print solution
print()
print('Problem #5')
print('Root 1: ',x9)
print('Root 2: ',x10)
```

I get this after i run it:

```
    x9 = (-B5 + math.sqrt(B5**2 - 4*A5*C5))/(2*A5)
ValueError: math domain error
```

I did the problem on paper and got an answer for both...

Comment: How did you get the square root of 0^2 - 4*5*6.5 = -130 on paper? Because that's what's happening here, i.e., that's the `math domain error`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ValueError: math domain error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890503/valueerror-math-domain-error)

Comment: Well, i used a calculator and only sqrt the -4(5)(6.5) and got 11.40 and then divided that by 10 and got 1.14 as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you got an answer, it must have been a complex number (which are not included by default in Python). Look at the line `math.sqrt(B5**2 - 4*A5*C5)`.

This evaluates as so:

```
math.sqrt(B5**2 - 4*A5*C5)
math.sqrt(0**2 - 4*5*6.5)
math.sqrt(0 - 130)
math.sqrt(-130)
```

The function `math.sqrt` doesn't find complex roots. You should use `cmath.sqrt` instead, as that does (this will require `import`ing  `cmath` at the start of your program).

Using `cmath`, I get this result:

```
Problem #5
Root 1:  1.1401754250991378j
Root 2:  1.1401754250991378j
```

(where `j` is the square root of -1).

Comment: Thanks dude! I'm also reading a python book, but i haven't seen cmath yet. Anyways, thanks!