# Why does math.sqrt result in ValueError: math domain error?

Tags: python, math, dns, sqrt

What causes the problem?

```
from math import sqrt
print "a : "
a = float(raw_input())
print "b : "
b = float(raw_input())
print "c : "
c = float(raw_input())
d = (a + b + c)/2
s = sqrt(d*(d-a)*(d-b)*(d-c))
print("a+b+c =", a, b, c)
print("Distr. =", d*2, "Area =", s)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Python27/fájlok/háromszög terület2.py", line 11, in <module>
       s = sqrt(d*(d-a)*(d-b)*(d-c))
ValueError: math domain error
```

---

<sub>See also: [Why does math.log result in ValueError: math domain error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890503) for the equivalent problem using `math.log`; [Python math domain error using math.acos function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955051/) for the equivalent problem using `math.acos`.</sub>

Comment: Check whether total of d*(d-a)*(d-b)*(d-c) is  positive because sqrt(-1) is complex number in math but not  in python

Comment: And generally, we ask that when you post "why am I getting this error?", you also include the input that causes that error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) holds good only when the sum of the two numbers are greater than the third. You need to check that explicitly.

A better way as you are using a code to do that is by using *Exception handling*

```
try:
    s = sqrt(d*(d-a)*(d-b)*(d-c))
    print "a+b+c =", a, b, c
    print "Distr. =", d*2, "Area =", s
except ValueError:
    print "Please enter 3 valid sides"
```

If you want to do it without `try` block you can do it as

```
delta = (d*(d-a)*(d-b)*(d-c))
if delta>0:
    s = sqrt(delta)
    print "a+b+c =", a, b, c
    print "Distr. =", d*2, "Area =", s
else:
    print "Please enter 3 valid sides"
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, just a comment: I can't use use 'del' as a variable

Comment: Oh yeah. It is a reserved word. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

`sqrt` gives that error when you try to use it with a negative number. `sqrt(-4)` gives that error because the result is a **complex number**.

For that, you need `cmath`:

```
>>> from cmath import sqrt
>>> sqrt(-4)
2j
>>> sqrt(4)
(2+0j)
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error with my code until I used `cmath` instead of `math` like aneroid said:

```
import sys
import random
import cmath

x = random.randint(1, 100)
y = random.randint(1, 100)

a = 2 * x * cmath.sqrt(1 - x * 2 - y * 2)
b = 2 * cmath.sqrt(1 - x * 2 - y * 2)
c = 1 - 2 * (x * 2 + y * 2)

print ( 'The point on the sphere is: ', (a, b, c) )
```

This way ran my code properly.

Comment: It was already proposed in another answer to use `cmath` instead of `math`.

Comment: I must of missed it. I had no intention of not giving proper credibility, and I am also new [profile wise] to stackoverflow. Sorry for the noobish tendencies.

Answer (score 1):

Use cmath instead..

```
import cmath
num=cmath.sqrt(your_number)
print(num)
```

Now regardless of whether the number is negetive or positive you will get a result...

Comment: The OP is trying to calculate the area of a triangle, it seems unlikely that returning a complex value for an ill-specified triangle is a good idea.

Comment: Then before entering the value use abs() to make sure the value is positive.....Then use math.sqrt()....

Comment: That's even worse! Now you're silently giving a known wrong answer to the problem, instead of giving any clue that something's wrong. If someone asks what the area of a triangle with sides 1, 2 and 5 is, the correct answer isn't 2.45j, and it's not 2.45. The correct answer is to give some kind of error with a message "No such triangle exists."

Comment: Hmmmmm.....Then first of all we need to check that the sides satisfy pythagorean theorem then proceed...