# Distance estimation - don't understand this Math domain error

Tags: python

I try to calculate distance between 2 locations but I have an error with this formula

```
acos(sin(latA)*sin(latB) + cos(latA)*cos(latB)*cos(abs(longB-longA)))
```

Here is my function to calculate distances :

```
def distanceGPS(latA, longA, latB, longB):
    """Retourne la distance en Kilomètres entre les 2 points A et B connus grâce à
       leurs coordonnées GPS (en radians).
    """
    latA, longA, latB, longB = deg2rad(latA, longA, latB, longB)

    print(latA)
    print(longA)
    print(latB)
    print(longB)

    # Rayon de la terre en mètres (sphère IAG-GRS80)
    RT = 6378.137
    # angle en radians entre les 2 points
    S = acos(sin(latA)*sin(latB) + cos(latA)*cos(latB)*cos(abs(longB-longA)))

    # distance entre les 2 points, comptée sur un arc de grand cercle
    return (S*RT)
```

Result of print :

```
lat    0.651706 
dtype: float64
lon   -0.079956
dtype: float64
0.6517058798628295
-0.07995634999527296
```

Here is my function to convert degrees to radian :

```
def deg2rad(latA, longA, latB, longB):
    """Convertit un angle "degrés décimaux" en "radians"
    """
    return latA/180*pi, longA/180*pi, latB/180*pi, longB/180*pi

def test_prediction(corpus, lat_moy, long_moy, i):
    """
    Cette fonction test si la localisation predite est a une distance inferieure a 100km de la localisation correct. 
    Si oui, alors on defini la prediction comme correct
    Si non, alors on defini la prediction comme non correct
    """

    for word in corpus.correct_localisation[i]:
        loc = geolocator.geocode(word)

        if loc is not None and distanceGPS(lat_moy, long_moy, loc.latitude, loc.longitude) <= 100:
            corpus.at[i, "test_pred"] = "OK"
            return
        else:
            corpus.at[i, "test_pred"] = "NOK"

    return
```

My error is :

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-18-75f41b231cbd> in <module>
>      11     df = coordonnees_article(corpus['article'][i])
>      12     lat_moy, long_moy = position_moyenne(outliers_coordonnees(df))
> ---> 13     test_prediction(corpus, lat_moy, long_moy, i)
>      14     print(i)
> 
> <ipython-input-17-47270c034d33> in test_prediction(corpus, lat_moy,
> long_moy, i)
>      11         print(loc)
>      12  #       try:
> ---> 13         if loc is not None and distanceGPS(lat_moy, long_moy, loc.latitude, loc.longitude) <= 100:
>      14             corpus.at[i, "test_pred"] = "OK"
>      15             return
> 
> <ipython-input-16-129df29f0484> in distanceGPS(latA, longA, latB,
> longB)
>      13     RT = 6378.137
>      14     # angle en radians entre les 2 points
> ---> 15     S = acos(sin(latA)*sin(latB) + cos(latA)*cos(latB)*cos(abs(longB-longA)))
>      16 
>      17     # distance entre les 2 points, comptée sur un arc de grand cercle
> 
> ValueError: math domain error
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What version of python are you using? Can you post the full traceback error?

Comment: Hi, Python 3.7. I have added the full error

Comment: I can't replicate the error, but I am guessing this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955051/python-math-domain-error-using-math-acos-function

Comment: It's correct i do a acos() on value superior to 1. But how can i avoid this error ?

Comment: This might help: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/arccos-x-where-x-1-or-x-1.527086/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the "weird" cases that you sometimes get, it's due to floating point inaccuracies.
For example if you run:

```
1.2 - 1.0 = 0.19999999999999996
```

We'd obviously expect it to say 0.2 but because of the way floating point numbers are represented (using a fixed number of binary digits), we get the result above.

How can you deal with that? You can either use the [decimal module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html) or round your values to a smaller number of decimal places.

If you use the **decimal** module in python:

```
from decimal import *

# the following sets the number of decimal places to 8
getcontext().prec = 8

# if you run
sin(latA)*sin(latB) + cos(latA)*cos(latB)*cos(abs(longB-longA))
# the output is
0.999999999999954

# if you use the decimal module
# (please note I am multiplying by 1 at the end)
Decimal(sin(latA)*sin(latB) + cos(latA)*cos(latB)*cos(abs(longB-longA)))*1
# the output is
Decimal('1.00000000000')
```

You can also use the round function and round your number to fewer decimal places:

```
x = 0.19999999999999996
round(x,8)
# the output is
0.2
```

In your case, although I did not get the domain error, I think the reason you are getting it is because your computer may calculate a value that is 1.000000000004 (for example). Consequently, when you try to take **acos(1.0000000004)** you get the domain error. Using either of the methods above to "round" your answer before invoking **acos** would likely solve the problem you are facing.