# TypeError: Can't convert 'complex' object to str implicitly error quadratic formula function (python)

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that will get and input from the user, place it in an array and then call a function with those 3 values where the calculation will be performed, however I seem to get the following two errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "..\Playground\", line 14,
>   in 
>       quad(p1,p2,p3)   File "..\Playground\", line 7, in quad
>       print("Solution 1: " + res1 + "Solution 2: " + res2) TypeError: Can't convert 'complex' object to str implicitly

Here is the entire code:

```
import cmath

def quad(a,b,c):
   r = (b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)
   res1 = ((-b) + cmath.sqrt(r))/2
   res2 = ((-b) - cmath.sqrt(r))/2
   print("Solution 1: " + res1 + "Solution 2: " + res2)

nums = input()
param = nums.split()
p1 = float(param[0])
p2 = float(param[1])
p3 = float(param[2])
quad(p1,p2,p3)
```

Comment: Do you understand what does the error mean/what function raises that? Research first please.

Comment: [Dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29375970/5267751)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python math domain error - sqrt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375970/python-math-domain-error-sqrt)

Comment: Have a look at `cmath`

Comment: replace math with cmath, however now a new error appeared: TypeError: Can't convert 'complex' object to str implicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem there is that the params you input can easily make the r variable a negative number, so you can't evaluate the sqrt of it.

However, since it looks like a script to solve quadratic equations, and b ** 2 - 4 * a * c < 0 means the equation has no solution, maybe you could try with this:

```
def quad(a,b,c):
   r = (b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)
   try:
       math.sqrt(r)
   except ValueError:
       print('No solution!')
       return
   res1 = ((-b) + math.sqrt(r))/2
   res2 = ((-b) - math.sqrt(r))/2

   print("Solution 1: " , res1,  "Solution 2: " , res2)
```

This way, the program will check wether you can do sqrt(r) or not.

Another viable solution is to add:

```
if r < 0:
    print("No solution!")
    return
```

after the r declaration, so it becomes:

```
def quad(a,b,c):
   r = (b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)
   if r < 0:
       print("No solution!")
       return
   res1 = ((-b) + math.sqrt(r))/2
   res2 = ((-b) - math.sqrt(r))/2

   print("Solution 1: " , res1,  "Solution 2: " , res2)

nums = input()
param = nums.split()
p1 = float(param[0])
p2 = float(param[1])
p3 = float(param[2])
quad(p1,p2,p3)
```

Also, note the correction I made to the final print statement, where I replaced:

```
print("Solution 1: " + res1 + "Solution 2: " + res2)
```

With:

```
print("Solution 1: " , res1,  "Solution 2: " , res2)
```

Your code would run into a TypeError because you were trying to sum strings, like "Solution 1" and "Solution 2" and floats, like res1 and res2

Comment: This is for solving it with math.
To use cmath, just take the Print statement.