# What isnt my python code running?

Tags: python, math, sqrt, math.sqrt

my code is giving me some errors
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 7, in 
ValueError: math domain error

```
  import math
  a= 3
  b= 5
  c= 2
  d= b^2 -4*a*c
  x1 = math.sqrt(d)
  print(x1)
```

Comment: I think `b^2` should probably be `b**2`

Comment: `^` is bitwise xor, you want to use `**` for exponentiation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: math domain error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890503/valueerror-math-domain-error)

Comment: So you're aware - "why isn't this code working?" is a defined "close" vote option on stack overflow in itself (people can vote to close a question so that it can't be answered unless the question is edited to meet the site guidelines). Your title is not helpful for others that might encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d` is negative when there are no real solutions, therefore its square roor is also not real:
Please also note that `b^2` is not b`squared`, it is `b xor 2`. for `b square`, use `b**2`, or `b*b`

```
import math

a = 3
b = 5
c = 2

d = b**2 - 4*a*c      # Attention, b^2 is not b square, use b**2
if d > 0:
    x1 = math.sqrt(d)
    print(x1)
else:
print("there are no real roots")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `d` is `-17` (You most probably wanted to use `**` instead of `^`)

**[What is the root of a negative number?](https://mathbitsnotebook.com/Algebra1/Radicals/RADNegativeUnder.html)**

[That is what the exception is saying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890503/valueerror-math-domain-error)