# Python,how to solve ValueError: math domain error

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, trigonometry, valueerror

I'm trying to get the result of this code:

```py
from math import cos, sin, atan2, sqrt
from numpy import rad2deg


dis_ab= 531466.5079260713
mid=(531353.2565883757, 10971.133034496568)
mid_angle_from_x_in_rad=1.5501517288292364
mid_angle_from_x_in_deg=88.8171516668233
gdt1_x=761708.6575534055
gdt1_y=3679240.5391967976
uav_x= 230355.40096502978
uav_y=3668269.406162301
angle=178.8171516668233




def find_point_for_second_gdt():
    dist_ab = sqrt(((gdt1_x - uav_x) ** 2) + ((gdt1_y - uav_y) ** 2))

    mid = (gdt1_x - uav_x), (gdt1_y - uav_y)
    mid_angle_from_x_in_rad = atan2(mid[0], mid[1])
    mid_angle_from_x_in_deg = (rad2deg(mid_angle_from_x_in_rad))

    angle = 90 + mid_angle_from_x_in_deg


    x = gdt1_x + (dis_ab * sqrt(2 * cos(angle)))
    y = gdt1_y + (dis_ab * sqrt(2 * sin(angle)))

    end_xy = (x, y)

    point_in_lat_lon = convert_to_lat_lon(end_xy)

    print(point_in_lat_lon)

output:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/TriangulationCalc/find_2nd_position.py", line 36, in <module>
    find_point_for_second_gdt()
    File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/TriangulationCalc/find_2nd_position.py", line 26, in find_point_for_second_gdt
    x = gdt1_x + (dis_ab * sqrt(2 * cos(angle)))
    ValueError: math domain erro

find_point_for_second_gdt()
```

I looked at this post:
[ValueError: math domain error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890503/valueerror-math-domain-error)

my thought by this was maybe to use abs() and round().

It didn't solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because `cos(angle)` equals `-0.9680080671170238`, so `2 * cos(angle)` is `-1.9360161342340476`, which means that `sqrt(2 * cos(angle))` is imaginary.

The builtin `math.sqrt` can't handle negative arguments, so it throws a ValueError.

If you really want to find the square root of a negative number, you can use the `sqrt` method from the `cmath` library:

```
from cmath import sqrt
```

which in this example would give:

```
>>> end_xy
((761708.6575534055+739486.7340101058j), (4055734.2602401497+0j))
```

Comment: this raises another error when trying to convert to lat lon , will edit to add that function. and new error raised

Comment: @yovelcohen please ask this as a new question.