# Convert this standard deviation Excel formula in Python

Tags: python, excel, for-loop, math

Please could someone help me convert this excel formula into python?
This is the formula I would like to use to calculate the standard deviation for each sample point between 2 lists.

Here are my 2 lists (dummy data):

```
P=[121,43.4,122.2,43.98]
N= [341,111,232,123]
```

Excel formula:
`=SQRT(P*((1-P)/N))`

My python code is:

```
my_data=[]
for p in list_p:
    for n in list_n:
        data= p*((1-p)/n))
        squared=sqrt(data)
        my_data.append(squared)
```

Please could someone help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: math domain error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890503/valueerror-math-domain-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your values for `p`, you are attempting to get the square root of a negative number, which will raise a `ValueError: math domain error`. I have written my answer below assuming that you use numbers that have defined square roots (e.g., `p` in [0, 1]).

The translation of your excel formula to python can be:

```
import math

def f(p, n):
    return math.sqrt(p * ((1 - p) / n))
```

Then, you can use `zip` to iterate through both lists at the same time and apply your function.

```
p = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
n = [341, 111, 232, 123]

results = []
for this_p, this_n in zip(p, n):
    result = f(p=this_p, n=this_n)
    results.append(result)
```

You can also write this as a list comprehension.

```
results = [f(i, j) for (i, j) in zip(p, n)]
```

Both methods give this output

```
[0.01624591083221647,
 0.03796631983009996,
 0.030086083390715772,
 0.04417261042993862]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I get `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'`, when inputting into function f, both are lists so not sure why this is happening?

Comment: You aren't copying and pasting my answer in that case. What did you change?

Comment: changed my p vals to:`p = [30.1, 17.6, 12.5, 9.7, 7.9, 6.7, 5.8, 5.1, 4.6]` and n values are similar to the numbers above, same list length. now I get 'math domain error'

Comment: sorry I had to divide my values by 100 as they are percentages - it worked after this! thanks so much